# How to show count of attachments uploaded for each List item in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

How to show count of attachments uploaded for each List item in SharePoint online using jsom or any other approach. Help me on this.

Comment: You can achieve this by creating event receiver on list item added event like given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4061ce50-3c80-476a-b978-af4f7ec17a59/column-to-show-count-of-attachments-uploaded-for-each-list-item-in-moss-2007?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy).

Answer (score 1):

Add the attachments field to the list view, and then add the code below into a script editor web part in this view.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it output render  
    var attachmentsFiledContext = {};
    attachmentsFiledContext.Templates = {};
    attachmentsFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {    
        "Attachments": { "View": AttachmentsFiledTemplate }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(attachmentsFiledContext);

})();
function AttachmentsFiledTemplate(ctx) {
    var itemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var listName = ctx.ListTitle;       
    return "Count:"+getAttachments(listName, itemId);
}
//get attachments field properties
function getAttachments(listName,itemId) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var requestUri = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
    var count = 0;
    // execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            count=data.d.results.length;                  
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //alert(err);
        }
    });
    return count;
}   
</script>
```

[image]

For modern list UI, as a workaround, we can create a new field "attachment", and using MS Flow to set values. You can refer to the article below.

[Display SharePoint Online List Attachments files within the List View in Modern UI](https://maruthigadde.com/2019/07/26/display-sharepoint-online-list-attachments-files-within-the-list-view-in-modern-ui/)